# Nest.js & Angular Universal session cookies not working

Tags: angular, express, session, cookies, nestjs

I am using the [express-sessions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) package together with [Nest.js](https://nestjs.com) and [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) for a server-side-rendered application. I am using session-cookies for authentication.

I set a custom attribute 'tokens' in my session-cookie which is then sent to the browser. But whenever I make a sub-sequent request to the server, the `req.session.tokens` is `undefined`. Although my `req.session` is defined.

Here's my Angular component which posts a request to the server when the component is initialized on the `ngOnInit`-lifecycle hook. The idea here is to get a session-cookie so I can determine whether the user is logged in or not.

```
export class LoginRequestAccessComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const options = {withCredentials: true}
    
    // Posting to server which sets attribute in session-cookies.
    this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:4200/api/auth", null, options)
      .subscribe()
  }
```

Here's what my server endpoint looks like:

```
  @Post('auth')
  async tokens(@Req() req: RequestModel) {
    
    // This is a simplified version for demonstrative purposes only
    req.session.tokens = {
      access_token: 'some-generated-token',
      token_type: 'Bearer',
      expires_in: 7200,
      refresh_token: 'some-generated-refresh-token',
      scope: 'custom_scopes',
      created_at: 1677607669
    }
    return
  }
```

I have a button connected to my `onClick()`-method which sends a request to the server which in turn console logs the session object on the request object. my `req.session.tokens` is then `undefined` as explained.

Here's my `onClick()`-method:

```
  onClick() {
    const options = {withCredentials: true}
    this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:4200/api/auth", options)
      .subscribe()
  }
```

My server endpoint looks like this:

```
  @Get('auth')
  async checkSessionTokens(@Req() req: RequestModel) {
    console.log(req.session.tokens) <-- undefined
  }
```

The `RequestModel` looks like this:

```
import { Request } from 'express';

export interface RequestModel extends Request {
  session: SessionModel;
}
```

And here's the SessionModel:

```
import { Session } from "express-session";

export interface SessionModel extends Session {
  tokens: Object
}
```

My express-session-cookie is configured as follows:

```
    app.use(
      session({
      name: 'My-Custom-Cookie-Name',
      secret: 'My-Super-Secret',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: { secure: false, httpOnly: false },
    })
```

I can see the Cookie in the browser and it's passed in the request. The strange part is that if I hook up a button which invokes the Post-request to the same endpoint `auth` which is called on my `ngOnInit`-method, then all sub-sequent request to the server contain the `req.session.tokens`

When I use Postman it works but not when calling the endpoint on `ngOnInit`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the network console?

Comment: No but if I set a window.timeout to delay the first call to the server it works. I know I shouldn't use window.timeout with SSR but did it for testing purposes. Maybe it's a timing issue before Angular has bootstrapped to the browser?

Comment: If I use: 
`if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) { 
    // Make calls to server api
}`

Before posting to my server it also works. I'm not really sure why though.